# Setting this.BindingContext = this; doesn't seem to work for my page and bindings in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
public partial class CFSPage : ContentPage
{
    SSVViewModel[] CardFrontSide = new[] {
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 0, Name=LANG.EnglishRomajiKanaKanji.Text(), IsSelected = false},
        new SSVViewModel {Id = 1, Name=LANG.EnglishRomajiKana.Text(), IsSelected = false}
    }

    public CFSPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    <Label Text="{Binding CardFrontSide[0].Name}" />
```

When I run the code the label does not display. Is there something wrong with the way I am specifying the binding context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For bindings to work they need to be public properties.

```
public SSVViewModel[] CardFrontSide { get; set; } = new[] {
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 0, Name=LANG.EnglishRomajiKanaKanji.Text(), IsSelected = false},
    new SSVViewModel {Id = 1, Name=LANG.EnglishRomajiKana.Text(), IsSelected = false}
}
```

Notice how I added the `{ get; set; }` and `public` part.

Answer (score 4):

`CardFrontSide` needs to be a public property